# Flexbox, how to keep a minimum of 2 cols at 400px?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flexboxgrid

https://codepen.io/leon-yum/pen/XYpgzj?editors=1100

I'm trying to make sure that on mobile (400px and below) that my flexbox grid sticks to 2 cols / boxes. However whatever I do, either it snaps to 1 column, or each row stays at 3 cols or 4 cols respectively.

**Expected at 400px width:**

[image]

**Results:**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-grid-thirds">
  <div class="col">This little piggy went to market.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy stayed home.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy had roast beef.</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-grid-four">
  <div class="col">This little piggy went to market.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy stayed home.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy had roast beef.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy had roast beef.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-grid-thirds,
.flex-grid-four {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.flex-grid-thirds .col {
  width: 32%;
}

.flex-grid-four .col {
  width: 24%;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .flex-grid-thirds,
  .flex-grid-four {
    .col {
      width: 40%;
    }
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.flex-grid { 
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.col {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: is the markup supposed to be like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrgZVa?editors=1100.
All you need, is just to put all items inside one wrapper element (now you have 2 elements), and give `flex-wrap: wrap` property to this wrapper. And another one thing to do: give the width to your items (percents are preferrable), and if you will give them `width: 50%`, there will be 2 columns, if `width: 33%` - 3 columns and so on. I didn't touch margins and such small stuff, just demonstrate what you asked for:

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-grid-thirds .col {
  width: 32%;
}

.flex-grid-four .col {
  width: 24%;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .flex-grid {
    .col {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.flex-grid { 
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.col {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="col">This little piggy went to market.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy stayed home.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy had roast beef.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy went to market.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy stayed home.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy had roast beef.</div>
  <div class="col">This little piggy had roast beef.</div>
</div>
```